# How to fix this undefined notice error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert $teacherId into the 'TeacherId' field in the database but for this to happen it needs to look up the teacher's username 'TeacherUsername' to be able to find the correct TeacherId which matches the teacher's username.

Problem is that I am getting a notice stating: 
Notice: Undefined index: teacherusername in /Mobile_app/QandATable2.php on line 27 which is here:

```
$teacherid = "SELECT TeacherId FROM (SELECT TeacherUsername from Teacher where TeacherUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teacherusername'])."')";
```

Why is it giving me this notice because there is nothing wrong with the $_POST method and it is works at the bottom here:

```
<?php echo $_POST['teacherusername']); ?>
```

Below is the full code:

```
<?php>

    session_start();

        $username="xxx";
        $password="xxx";
        $database="mobile_app";

        mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

        @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

        $teacherid = "SELECT TeacherId FROM (SELECT TeacherUsername from Teacher where TeacherUsername = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['teacherusername'])."')";

        $sql="INSERT INTO Session (TeacherId)
        VALUES
        (' ". mysql_real_escape_string( $teacherid ) . "')";

        mysql_query($sql);

        mysql_close();
?>

<?php echo $_POST['teacherusername']); ?>
```

Comment: What's in `$_POST`?  Can you do a `print_r($_POST)`?  Keep in mind that array indices are case sensitive.

Comment: You might have an invisible character in the first `$_POST['teacherusername']`. Try deleting it and re-writing it.

Comment: In $_POST['teacherusername'], it posts a username the teacher has entered in a textbox in the previous page. So for example I typed in 'j.lu' in the textbox and when I submit form it shows in the echo you see 'j.lu'. So the $_POST works but it doesn't recognise it in the query I am trying to do

Comment: @MichaelRushton Hi, I rewrote it but it still comes up with the notice

Comment: Do `var_dump($_POST['teacherusername']);` above the query.

Comment: Right, did a var dump and it came with a NULL. But I change $_POST to $_SESSION because I mentioned this at the bottom if (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) {

$_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $_POST['teacherusername'];

}. but problem is that in the database it suppose to state 'T1' in the TeacherId field but instead it is stating 'SEL'. What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

If this script is run ONLY when a POST has occurred and you are convinced that teacherusername SHOULD be set then you may want to var_dump($_POST) and double check that the form really is passing a teacherusername field.

Otherwise if the field is supposed to be optional, try:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) {
    echo $_POST['teacherusername'];
}
?>
```

This will only echo the post index is post is set and so is the field in question. You could even add an else to handle the error properly. Such as sending back a "this field is required" message.

Hope this helps,

ise

Comment: Right, did a var dump and it came with a NULL. But I change $_POST to $_SESSION because I mentioned this at the bottom if (isset($_POST['teacherusername'])) { $_SESSION['teacherusername'] = $_POST['teacherusername']; }. but problem is that in the database it suppose to state 'T1' in the TeacherId field but instead it is stating 'SEL'. What does this mean?

Comment: If var_dump($_POST) is null then you are not correctly submitting your form. Ensure that your <form> tag is correctly formed with attribute method="post".